# How to make card sets spread?

Tags: swift, swiftui, rotation, effect, card

I want to spread the card set around,
but I can't make it into that shape even if I try it.
I need help.

GPT says to use sin and cos with it, but I'm not familiar with sin and cos and SwiftUI.

```
        var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(0..<10) { num in
                VStack {
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        ZStack {
                            CardFront(width: width, height: height, num: num, degree: $frontDegrees[num])
                            CardBack(width: width, height: height, degree: $backDegrees[num])
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            flipCard(num)
                        }

                        // spread the cards based on the center
                        .offset(x: ((Double(num) + 0.6) * 90), y: 600).rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(num) * 6))
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CardFlipView()

        CardFlipView()
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
    }
}
```

[image: card set preview]

How it should look:

[image: how should be]

Comment: ChatGPT is, essentially, correct. The idea is that you place the centers of the cards on a perimeter of an imaginary circle (you would use trigonometric functions `sin()` and `cos()` for that) and then rotate cards for axes to intersect in the center of the imaginary circle, however, it's a little too late now where I'm from so let's confuse ChatGPT with this implementation (no explicit trigonometry necessary): https://gist.github.com/Baglan/c08a30b1aa029be773f35a1772e99e16 (you can run it as a Playground or adapt the code for a preview). Let me know if you need more details :)

Comment: You can use `.offset(x: width*2, y: 0)` and `.rotationEffect(angle)` you don't need to calculate x and y. With some arithmetic you can calculate the angles for each card based on the start-end and the number of cards. Using `sin` and `cos` is trigonometry, "finding the point of a circle" which translates to `position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a go at getting an example to work. Tap the cards to toggle the fanned state:

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// Encapsulates the layout logic for the cards
class Layout {

    /// The width available for showing the fanned cards
    let viewWidth: CGFloat

    /// The number of cards in the pack
    static let nCardsInPack = 10

    /// The width of a single card
    static let cardWidth = CGFloat(50)

    /// The height of a single card
    static let cardHeight = CGFloat(cardWidth * 1.4)

    /// The number of degrees for the arc of the spread.
    private static let arcDegrees = CGFloat(40)

    /// The number of radians for the arc of the spread.
    /// NB: 180 degrees = Pi radians
    private static let arcRadians = (arcDegrees * CGFloat.pi) / 180

    /// Creates the layout for showing the fanned cards, dependent on the supplied view width
    init(viewWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.viewWidth = viewWidth
    }

    /// - Returns the angle for the specified card when the pack is shown fanned
    func angleForCard(n: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let nGaps = max(CGFloat(Layout.nCardsInPack) - 1, 1)
        let fraction = (CGFloat(n) - (nGaps / 2)) / nGaps
        return fraction * Layout.arcRadians
    }

    /// - Returns the radius of the circle on which the fanned cards are
    /// spread out. Computed from the view width and arc for the spread
    private lazy var fanRadius: CGFloat = {
        let sinAngle = sin(Layout.arcRadians / 2.0)
        let availableWidth = (viewWidth - Layout.cardWidth) / 2.0
        return sinAngle == 0 ? availableWidth : availableWidth / sinAngle
    }()

    /// - Returns the x offset for card n, which may be negative
    func xOffsetForCard(n: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return sin(angleForCard(n: n)) * fanRadius
    }

    /// - Returns the y offset for card n
    func yOffsetForCard(n: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return fanRadius - (cos(angleForCard(n: n)) * fanRadius)
    }
}

/// View of an individual card
struct CardView: View {

    /// The index of this card in the pack, 0-based
    private let n: Int

    private let layout: Layout

    @Binding private var showSpreadOut: Bool

    init(n: Int, layout: Layout, showSpreadOut: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.n = n
        self.layout = layout
        self._showSpreadOut = showSpreadOut
    }

    private var angle: CGFloat {
        showSpreadOut ? layout.angleForCard(n: n) : 0
    }

    private var xOffset: CGFloat {
        showSpreadOut ? layout.xOffsetForCard(n: n) : 0
    }

    private var yOffset: CGFloat {
        showSpreadOut ? layout.yOffsetForCard(n: n) : 0
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(n)")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: Layout.cardWidth, height: Layout.cardHeight)
            .background(
                Color.blue
                    .opacity(0.2)
                    .cornerRadius(Layout.cardWidth / 10)
            )
            // Important: rotation must come before offsets!
            .rotationEffect(Angle(radians: angle))
            .offset(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: showSpreadOut)
    }
}

/// View of a collection of cards
struct PackView: View {

    private let layout: Layout

    @Binding private var showSpreadOut: Bool

    init(layout: Layout, showSpreadOut: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.layout = layout
        self._showSpreadOut = showSpreadOut
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            ForEach(0..<Layout.nCardsInPack, id: \.self) { n in
                CardView(n: n, layout: layout, showSpreadOut: $showSpreadOut)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showSpreadOut = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            PackView(
                layout: Layout(viewWidth: proxy.size.width),
                showSpreadOut: $showSpreadOut
            )
            .onTapGesture { showSpreadOut.toggle() }
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: FannedCards]

Comment: thx, gonna try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple attempt that only requires basic match setup. The provided `ViewModifier`s take care of the trigonometry.

```
struct HandView3: View {
    let cards: [Int] = Array(1...10)
    var angles: [Angle] {
        let angleSpread = 90.0 //spread hand for 90 degrees
        let startAngle = -130.0//left side of the hand
        let interval = angleSpread/Double(cards.count) //Find allotted angle per card
        return stride(from: startAngle, to: startAngle + angleSpread, by: interval).map { n in
            Angle(degrees: n)//Create the array
        }
    }
    let offset = 200.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ForEach(angles, id:\.degrees){ angle in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.6))

                .frame(width: offset/2)
                .offset(x: offset, y: 0)
                .aspectRatio(1.5, contentMode: .fit)
                .rotationEffect(angle)
                .shadow(radius: 6)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to do things like flipping the card, you can put the card view in a subview so you can control them individually.

```
struct HandView3: View {
    let cards: [Int] = Array(1...10)
    var angles: [Angle] {
        let angleSpread = 90.0 //spread hand for 90 degrees
        let startAngle = -130.0//left side of the hand
        let interval = angleSpread/Double(cards.count) //Find alloted angle per card
        return stride(from: startAngle, to: startAngle + angleSpread, by: interval).map { n in
            Angle(degrees: n)//Create the array
        }
    }
    let offset = 200.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ForEach(Array(zip(angles, cards)), id:\.0.degrees){ (angle, card) in
                CardView3(angle: angle, card: card)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct CardView3: View{
    @State private var flip:Bool = false
    let angle: Angle
    let card: Int
    let offset = 200.0
    var body: some View{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .fill(Color.blue.opacity(flip ? 0.9 : 0.6))
            .overlay {
                if flip{
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                        .overlay {
                            Text(card.description).font(.title)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                        }.padding(18)
                        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(flip ? 180 : 0), axis:(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
                }
            }
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(flip ? 180 : 0), axis:(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
            .animation(.spring(), value: flip)
            .frame(width: offset/2)
            .offset(x: offset, y: 0)
            .aspectRatio(1.5, contentMode: .fit)
            .rotationEffect(angle)
            .shadow(radius: 6)
            .zIndex(flip ? 1 : 0)
            .onTapGesture {
                flip.toggle()
            }
        
    }
}
```

[image]